# AoE 2 DE - Modding a building to have two page interface

Tags: modding, rts

I am using Advanced Genie Editor and currently trying to create a copy of a Krepost and give it a second page of units (like the docks).
I have so far been unable to do it as the second page just doesn't show up. The unit's train button is, of course, numbered to appear on the second page (i.e. 21). I tried changing the interface to match that of the dock (i.e. 2) but to no avail. Anyone have any idea regarding how to do it?

Comment: Modding questions are welcome here, but I can guarantee you won't get a response on this topic here. AoE 2, brilliant game though it is, is too old, and your question is very, very specific. I'd suggest seeking answer on AoE2 modding forums / IRC channels etc. which you can find on google.

Comment: Since they recently launched a new version I was hoping there would be some reignited interest in the game.Thanks anyways. I will try asking on their forums.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the two-page interface is hardcoded to docks and cannot be used by any other building, default or mod.